# Laravel Select Row with Unique column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have one database as follow:

```
id, shop, order_number, Price
1,  google, 11, 20
2,  apple, 12, 20
3, google, 13, 20
4, google, 11, 20,
5, google, 11 , 20
```

If I use the follow command in laraval:

```
Order::where('shop','=','google')->orderBy('id','desc')->get()->toArray();
```

It will perfectly show me results where shop is google.

however, i want to return only unique results by order_number and where shop is google. It should return following result:

```
1,  google, 11, 20
3, google, 13, 20
```

I try to use the following method:

```
Order::distinct()->where('shop','=','google')->orderBy('id','desc')->get(['id,shop,order_number,price'])->toArray();
```

But it seems not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax wrong: QueryBuilder get() expects an array of columns, so it should be like this:

```
Order::distinct()->where('shop','=','google')->orderBy('id','desc')->get(['id','shop','order_number','price'])->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
Order::distinct()
->select('id','shop','order_number','price') //if you are selecting all column no need to write select
->where('shop','=','google')
->orderBy('id','desc')
->groupBy('order_number')
->get()
->toArray();
```